# NoSuchMethodError in JAVA when using forEach Method

Tags: java, rest

I have below code snipet :

```
JSONArray processNodes = new JSONObject(customCon.geteOutput())
                        .getJSONArray("process-node");
processNodes.forEach(item -> {JSONObject node = (JSONObject) item;});
```

I added dependency in pom.xml as :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

But runtime it gives error as java.lang.NoSuchMethodError :org.json.JSONArray.forEach(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)

Any idea why i am having this error ?

Comment: There is a mismatch between the version of `JSONArray` that you compiled against and the one that you are using at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why I am having this error ?

There is a mismatch between the version of `JSONArray` that you compiled against and the one that you are using at runtime.  That causes the error.

According to the [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.json/json/20160810/org/json/JSONArray.html) for the 20160810 version in your POM file, there is a `forEach` method on `org.json.JSONArray` that is defined by the `Iterable` interface.

However it is clear from the exception that the version of `JSONArray` that you are using at runtime does not have that method.

Note that the method is not present in the Android version (see https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray) and won't be present in versions prior to Java 8 ... because Java 7 `Iterable` doesn't have a `forEach` method ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)).

Comment: i added now  <version>20200518</version>but still shows the same error

Comment: It is the JAR file that is being used at runtime is the problem.  Not the build-time dependency.  Check where `JSONArray` is >>actually<< being loaded from at runtime.

Comment: sorry to ask but how do i chech that ?

Comment: How are you running the code?  In a web container?  Which one?

Comment: i am running code in another server,i.e Amazon instance.i deploy my jar file inside war file and deploying that war file inside server.

Answer (score 0):

Check for correct import statement.Your Code seems fine.
I did quick check in Eclipse works fine.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          
                JSONObject jo =   new JSONObject(5);
                jo.put("red",new JSONArray(List.of(1,2,3,4,5)));
                jo.put("blue", "green");

         
          
          jo.getJSONArray("red").forEach(item -> {String var = item.toString();});

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because while running, the jar is picking from the jar folder of Spark, inorder to override this, specify the jar in --jar of spark submit and also add conf like this :

```
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=json-20200518.jar 
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=json-20200518.jar
```

https://hadoopsters.com/2019/05/08/how-to-override-a-spark-dependency-in-client-or-cluster-mode/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem while running my Spring Boot application together with [Spring Boot Configuration Properties Migrator](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-properties-migrator).
The problem is correctly described [in the answer by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792686/nosuchmethoderror-in-java-when-using-foreach-method/63793132#63793132) : Spring Boot Migrator depends on old JSON handling library - `android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1` and another library in my application depends on newer `json:20210307`.

The solution for this case is to add the Migrator library excluding the old JSON handling library to avoid later loading of classes from it during runtime:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```